# Opencv - create png image

Tags: opencv, png

As part of my project I wanted to send stream of images using websockets from embedded machine to client application and display them in `img` tag to achieve streaming.

Firstly I tried to send raw RGB data (752*480*3 - something about 1MB) but in the end I got some problems with encoding image to png in javascript based on my RGB image so I wanted to try to encode my data to PNG firstly and then sent it using websockets.

The thing is, I am having some problems with encoding my data to PNG using `OpenCV` library that is already used in the project.

Firstly, some code:

```
websocketBrokerStructure.matrix = cvEncodeImage(0, websocketBrokerStructure.bgrImageToSend, 0);
websocketBrokerStructure.imageDataLeft = websocketBrokerStructure.matrix->rows * websocketBrokerStructure.matrix->cols *  websocketBrokerStructure.matrix->step;
websocketBrokerStructure.imageDataSent = 0;
```

but I am getting strange error during execution of the second line:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid
```

and I am a bit confused why I am getting this error from my code.

Also I am wondering if I understand it right: after invoking cvEncodeImage (where `bgrImage` is `IplImage*` with 3 channels - BGR) I just need to iterate through `data` member of my `CvMat`to get all of the png encoded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cvEncodeImage` function takes as its first parameter the extension of the image you want to encode. You are passing `0`, which is the same thing as `NULL`. That's why you are getting the message `NULL not valid`.

You should probably use this:

```
websocketBrokerStructure.matrix = cvEncodeImage(".png", websocketBrokerStructure.bgrImageToSend, 0);
```

You can check out the documentation of `cvEncodeImage` [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode).

You can check out some examples of `cvEncodeImage`, or its C++ brother `imencode` here: [encode_decode_test.cpp](https://code.google.com/p/opencvjp-sample/source/browse/trunk/cpp/encode_decode_test.cpp?r=63). They also show some parameters you can pass to `cvEncodeImage` in case you want to adjust them.